# PostgreSQL plpgsql: Generate series not working for dec month

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, generate-series

I am trying to generate a series a tables dynamically based on to and from months but with the code i am having, it is not generating for the December month. Appreciate all your help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "gracenote"."fn_gn_tv_schedule_tables_test" ()  RETURNS void
  VOLATILE
AS $dbvis$
DECLARE
      today_date TEXT;
      partitionn TEXT;
      partition_check TEXT;
      part_table_from DATE;
      part_table_to DATE;
      part_from DATE;
      part_to DATE;
      constrnt TEXT;
      indx TEXT;
      createStmts TEXT;
      create_query TEXT;
      index_query TEXT;
      delete_query TEXT;
BEGIN
    today_date := to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMM');
    partition_check := 'gn_tv_schedule_test' || '_' || today_date;
    partitionn := 'gracenote.gn_tv_schedule_test' || '_' || today_date;
    part_from := DATE(TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM') || '-01');
    part_to := DATE(TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 month', 'YYYY-MM' ) || '-01');
    part_table_from := DATE (TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 month','YYYY-MM') || '-01');
    part_table_to := DATE(TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '4 month', 'YYYY-MM' ) || '-01');
    constrnt := 'gn_tv_schedule_cnstrt_test_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM');
    indx := 'gn_tv_schedule_idx_test_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM');


    FOR create_query, index_query IN SELECT
            'CREATE TABLE gracenote.gn_tv_schedule_test_' || TO_CHAR(d, 'YYYYMM') || ' (CONSTRAINT gn_tv_schedule_cnstrt_test_' || TO_CHAR(d, 'YYYYMM') || ' check (( date >= date ''' 
            || TO_CHAR(d, 'YYYY-MM-01') || ''') and (date < date ''' || TO_CHAR(d + INTERVAL '1 month','YYYY-MM-01') || '''))) INHERITS (gracenote.gn_tv_schedule_panda);',
            'CREATE INDEX gn_tv_schedule_idx_test_' || TO_CHAR(d, 'YYYYMM') || ' ON gracenote.gn_tv_schedule_test_' || TO_CHAR(d, 'YYYYMM') || '(date);'
        FROM generate_series(part_table_to, part_table_from, '1 month' ) AS d
    LOOP
           IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition_check) THEN

              EXECUTE create_query;
              EXECUTE index_query;
           END IF;
    END LOOP;

END;
$dbvis$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The output is the tables are created from 'gn_tv_schedule_test_201807' to 'gn_tv_schedule_test_201811'. The 'gn_tv_schedule_test_201812' is not getting created.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `DATE(TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY-MM') || '-01');` can be simplified to `date_trunc('month', current_date)` - the same can be applied to the other nested `date(to_char())` calls

Comment: `generate_series(part_table_to, part_table_from, '1 month' )` should be `generate_series(part_table_from, part_table_to, '1 month' )`